# I wrote a program to print all primes number up-to a given a number

Tags: c, primes

```
#include<stdio.h>

float abso(float a)
{
    if(a<0.0)
        return(-1*a);
    else
        return a;
}

int sqert(int x)
{
    float x1 = (float)x;
    float g1, g2;
    g1 = x1/2.0;
    g2 = x1/g1;
    double e=0.000000001;
    int sr;
    while(abso(g1-g2)>=e)
    {
        g2 = (g1+x1/g1)/2.0;
        g1 = x1/g2;
    }
    sr = (int)g1;
    return(sr);
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    //num = 0;
    printf("Enter a num between 1 and 1000 ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    //printf("hello");
    int flag;
    flag = 0;
    int i;
    i = 2;
    int m, j;
    m = j = 0;

    while(i<=num)
    {
        flag = 1;
        if(i==2)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
            i++;
        }
        else if(i==3)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
            i= i+2;
        }
        else if(i>3)
        {
            m = sqert(i);
            for(j=2;j<=m;j++)
            {
                if((i%j) == 0)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(flag == 0)
            {
                i = i + 2;
                continue;
            }    

            if(j==m+1)
                printf("%d ",i);

            i = i + 2;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Here `sqert` function is taking square root of the input value and abso function is taking the absoulte value of given value.

The logic used is simple we are iterating to the square root of that number and then check for every number if it is divisible by any other number than itself then it is not a prime number else it is a prime number.

But this program is working only for value upto 5. After that it is not printing anything. It is not printing the entered number also.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since `g1` and `g2` are floats the absolute difference might never be less than `e`, due to rounding errors. A `float` only has 6 or 7 digits of precision, so try `e=0.00001`. You might also want to read [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Run the program in a debugger, or add printf statements to show the values of important variables and compare them to what you would expect. Find out where the differences come from, and fix it.

Comment: What happens if you use the square root function provided by math lib? Trying that would allow to narrow the search down to the code outside of sqert or to within.

Comment: @TheWinterSoldier For a significantly more efficient approach to prime numbers, see [Sieve of Eratosthenes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)  Also see [John Carmack's, Fast Inverse Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Comment: Beware! When I did conversions of float to integers, I always used rounding (`i = (int) (f+.5);`) instead of truncating (`i = (int) f;`). I was once bitten for not doing it...

Comment: Foating point calculations in this kind of program make no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to compare `float` with `double`.

```
while(abso(g1-g2)>=e)
```

This is not correct because of the difference in precision between `float` and `double`.

`double` has 2 times more precision than `float`.

`float` is a 32 bit IEEE 754 single precision floating point number
(1 bit for the sign, 8 bits for the exponent, and 23* for the value),
i.e. float has 7 decimal digits of precision.

`double` is a 64 bit IEEE 754 double precision floating point number
(1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52* bits for the value),
i.e. double has 15 decimal digits of precision.

Declare `e` as `float` and make sure it is assigned a value that fits with the precision of `float`.
Something like:

```
float e = 0.00001;
```

Then your code will work as intended.

@EricPostpischil in the comments said that the `sqert` function may not always return the correct approximation. This is correct. 
So it is better to use `sqrt` from `math.h` which works perfectly instead of `sqert`.

Comment: Or, just use `double` throughout the whole code. In modern days, (unless dealing with embedded systems / other systems with very limited resources) there's not much point in using `float` anyway...

Comment: While the program has problems using floating-point, this answer misdiagnoses the problem. Comparing a `float` value with a `double` value does not cause any problem. The `float` value will be converted to `double` without any error, and the comparison will proceed correctly. Furthermore, the recommended fix is dubious. It still leaves `sqert` returning an approximation. Has it been evaluated to ensure the approximation is good enough? E.g., if the function returns 6.99…9 for `sqert(49)`, the program may report 49 to be prime even though it is not.

Comment: For the value of e suggested in the answer, I checked if the program prints all the primes upto 1000 (which was the requirement).   `printf("Enter a num between 1 and 1000 ");` And it does print all of them.

Comment: @user846834: I am skeptical. When I set `e` to `0.00001` as suggested in the answer now, the output includes 961, which is 31•31. When I set it to the `0.000001` suggested in a previous answer, the program hangs. When I have `e` at that value but change all `float` to `double`, the program includes 49, which is 7•7. The method you are using to end the loop is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree with you. The `sqert` function used by the OP is not something I would use. `sqrt()` from `math.h` works perfectly.

Comment: @user846834: Some implementations of `sqrt`, such as Microsoft’s return approximations, including incorrect values for some inputs that are perfect squares. For example, as with OP’s code, `sqrt` might return 28.99…5 for `sqrt(841)`. Their code should be rewritten to use a different test that does not use a square root at all, or that uses a square root that is guaranteed not to return a result that is too low.